# Extjs/Spring MVC with file upload returning Content-Type application/x-ms-application instead of text/html for IE8

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

I have an Extjs (4.1) application using Spring MVC (3.0.2). On one of the forms I have a filefield.  When the form is submitted in IE8 the success/failure callbacks are not hit.  The app works properly in FF, Chrome and IE9.  I noticed today the response Content-Type equals application/x-ms-application in IE8.  For IE9 it is text/html.  I am returning json from the Spring Controller.

Is this a known issue or is there a Spring configuration option I need to set?  I am new to Spring.  Here is a link to this same question on the Sencha forum: [extjs 4.1 forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226520-Not-hitting-success-failure-calls-on-form.submit-in-IE8).  I would appreciate any help since my client is required to use IE8.

I have written a sample application that shows the behavior I can post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct.  I updated my Spring MVC Controller class to explicitly return a Content-Type of "text/html"

Original code:

```
    public @ResponseBody String importData(@RequestParam String groupName, @RequestParam String processType,
                @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile spreadsheet) throws Exception
{

.
.
.
     return "{success:true}";
}
```

Updated Code:

```
    public void importData(@RequestParam String groupName, 
                @RequestParam String processType,
                FileUploadBean uploadItem, 
                BindingResult result, 
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
.
.
.
            // return data
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.getWriter().write("{success:true}");
            response.flushBuffer();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set your response content type explicitly in your Spring controller. Kinda like this:
response.setContentType("text/html")

See this doc for explanation: ( something about a hidden IFrame :) )
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload